# API Manager returns this warning - APIThrottleHandler Unable to load throttle context

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, throttling

I use API Manger that consist of 3 clustered Gateway worker.
When gateway workers receive API request from users, All gateways show up warning message like below. It seems to come from something mis configuration..

every reply will be helpful.

```
2016-11-28 21:11:46,596 [-] [HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-4]  WARN AccessConfiguration Error loading properties from file: access-log.properties
2016-11-28 21:11:47,303 [-] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-6]  WARN APIThrottleHandler Unable to load throttle context
2016-11-28 21:11:47,303 [-] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-15]  WARN APIThrottleHandler Unable to load throttle context
2016-11-28 21:11:47,341 [-] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-13]  WARN APIThrottleHandler Unable to load throttle context
2016-11-28 21:11:47,356 [-] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-16]  WARN APIThrottleHandler Unable to load throttle context
2016-11-28 21:11:47,363 [-] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-1]  WARN APIThrottleHandler Unable to load throttle context
```

Comment: What is your APIM version?

Comment: APIM version is 1.10.0

Comment: Does this happen to a particular API or all APIs?

Comment: @Bhathiya all APIs...